# C for loop continues incrementation

Tags: c, arrays, loops

*Newb* here.
I'm probably missing something trivial but:
Here's the thing: http://i.imgur.com/8BmPci5.png

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Sort Numbers (zuerst)
    int numbers [10];
    int i,j;
    j = 0;
    int read;
    printf("Input numbers: \n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
            scanf("%d",&read);
            if (read == 27) {
                break;
            } else {
                numbers[i] = read;
                j++;
            }
    }
    printf("j is: %d, i is: %d\n", j, i);
    for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
        printf("numbers[%d] is: %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input numbers: 
1
2
3
^[
j is: 10, i is: 10
numbers[0] is: 1
numbers[1] is: 2
numbers[2] is: 3
numbers[3] is: 3
numbers[4] is: 3
numbers[5] is: 3
numbers[6] is: 3
numbers[7] is: 3
numbers[8] is: 3
numbers[9] is: 3
```

I have a for loop (goes from 0 to <10). I also have a scanf inside which scans for an int. If it ain't ESC (ASCII 27), then it puts it into an array and it increments the value of j. If it's an ESC, it ('s supposed to) break (exit the loop). Later, only j (or j-1) number of array items would be printed.
Issue: **j (and i too) increments to 10, even if break is called** at ~ i = 3 or 4.
Break supposed to exit the for loop without doing anything after it's called, right? Quote from BeginnersBook.com:

> It is used to come out of the loop instantly. When a break statement is encountered inside a loop, the control directly comes out of loop and the loop gets terminated. It is used with if statement, whenever used inside loop.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your screenshot is *not* particularly useful.  If your question is about code (and most questions appropriate for SO are) then the relevant code should be presented *in the question itself*, *as text*.  Copy&paste is your friend in this regard.

Comment: Your screenshot is ... unfortunately, unhelpful. Please post the code in the question instead of a image.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The screenshot shows the code just fine to my eyes AND it shows output.

Comment: Pasting the code allows us to easily try it out for ourselves.

Comment: The problem is with the value of j and i, respectively. Edit: added code.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Never. No, really never.

Comment: The problem is that ESC is a single (non-numeric) character, and you attempt to read strings of numeric characters into ints with `"%d"`

Comment: Quote from another StackOverflow question:
"A char in C is already a number (the character's ASCII code), no conversion required." Aint that true backwards too? Also, it does break (condition is fulfilled), but incrementation continues.

Comment: @Samuel_Ch 

It is, but with "%d" you read '1' as 1, not as 49, which is it's ASCII value

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. There's enough here for this to be answerable now.

Comment: `read` is a well known C library function.  It is poor programming practice to use variable names that are the same as function names.

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%d",&read);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the '%d' will only input values '0`,,, `9`  so will never input an `escape` character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being naughty in that you're not checking the *return value* of `scanf`, which will tell you the number of variables that were successfully populated. In your case, you want that to be 1 to signal that something was read into your variable `read`.

If you try to pass `\033` (ASCII encoded ESC), then `scanf` will fail to parse that to an `int`. Then the previous value of `read` will be retained (which could give you undefined effects if it hasn't yet been set to anything), and `read == 27` will almost certainly be `0`. That behaviour accounts for the output you are observing.

If `scanf` *does* fail, you could try reading a `char` from the stream, and check if that is equal to `\033`.